# How did Frank put the bomb in the plane?

Tags: plot-explanation, red-2

*(warning: spoilers ahead)*

In *Red 2*, During the final scenes, we see Frank and Marvin crash with the bomb in the helicopter. Then Frank and Sarah get to the plane, where Bailey is waiting for them. After a brief exchange and after Sarah leaves, Bailey tells frank to take the bomb with him and leaves on the plane.

We do not see Frank put the bomb in the plane, yet that's where it is after Beiley leaves. So, how did he do it?

Answer (score 3):

When Frank boards the plane he comes up the stairs at the front of the aircraft and into the main cabin...carrying a box, supposedly with the bomb inside.

Bailey is standing at the rearmost part of the plane...

[image]

When Frank is forced to leave he takes the box and goes down the stairs...

[image]

Bailey then closes the door and enters the cockpit and takes off..but hears the sound of the bomb counting down.

He exits the cockpit and enters the doorway between the cockpit and and the main cabin and opens the panel..which was out of sight from Bailey's original position in the main cabin...

[image]

...and there is the bomb.

[image]

So, knowing that he couldn't stop the countdown, when Frank first ascended the stairs, **out of sight of Bailey** he opened the panel, placed the bomb and continued with an **empty** box.